# Как вывести переменную из JS в HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html, переменные

У меня есть переменная data из js скрипта в html. Как это сделать?
Я попробовал сделать это функцией:

```js
  function GetDivElement() {
    return data;
  }
```

Если она работает, то как проверить это в коде html? Как вывести переменную на экран в динамическом режиме, то есть без обновления страницы?

Comment: А как оно у вас обновляется? Функция, которая будет её обновлять, должна уметь после этого заодно и вывести значение куда надо. Или "обновляющую" часть писали не вы и нет возможности там что-то изменить?

Comment: Я имею ввиду, что не нужно перезагружать страницу, например, нажав на стрелочку в chrome.

Answer (score 3):

```
//... Код перед
let element = document.querySelector('#id');

element.innerHTML = data;
```

`let element = document.querySelector('#id');` - получает элемент с `id = #id`, к примеру, есть в html коде тег `<p id="tag"></p>`.

1. Получаем элемент по id: `let element = document.querySelector('#id');`
2. Устанавливаем значения тела тега `<p id="tag">`: `element.innerHTML = data;`

Телом тега является все что между `<p> тут тело </p>`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97922/discussion-on-answer-by-mully-----js--html).

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать планирование вызова через **setInterval**:
https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval

```js
var element = document.getElementById("content"),
    someData = 0;

function GetDivElement() {
    someData++;
    element.innerHTML= someData;
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  setInterval('GetDivElement()',500);
});
```

```html
<div id="content"></div>
```

Но я рекомендую использовать какой-то реактивный движок, например Vue.js или React. Vue.js позволяет начать разработку сразу:
https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html

```js
var app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        someData: 0
      },
      methods: {
        startInterval: function() {
          setInterval(() => {
            this.someData++
          }, 500);
        }
      },
      mounted: function() {
        this.startInterval()
      }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ someData }}
</div>
```

В данном примере функция **startInterval** нужна только для изменения значения **someData**, в теле документа она изменяется автоматически.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]